# Python framework for CLI development

Tags: python, django, command-line-interface

Need to write python CLI scripts - basic functionalities include - expose REST APIs, consume REST APIs, connect to Oracle/sql-server etc.Hooking onto a front end is not an immediate requirement - but its a possibility.

Checked [here](https://realpython.com/python-application-layouts/), [here](https://medium.com/@trstringer/the-easy-and-nice-way-to-do-cli-apps-in-python-5d9964dc950d) etc. - came to realize that there is no file structure which is universally accepted.

Checked various frameworks like `click`, `cement`, `django`, `flask` etc. - kind of decided on django(as may need to hook a front-end later in time).Here are my concerns:

1. Is it an overkill to use django for CLI development
2. Do we get all features of django(like ORM etc.) if we choose to run from CLI(without web server)
3. If I start with click(for example), how difficult will it be to hook front end in future

Please advice.

Comment: Try argparse package of Python. Yes django is an overkill for CLI program.  You can also go for 'docopt' if you find argparse difficult.

Comment: if you need only CLI then use argparse, click, docopt, (probably Google create `fire` for CLI), fabric, invoke, etc. If you plan to create web API then maybe start with django to create web api and then you can use CLI directly in django or you can use any other module to create CLI program which uses HTTP to conect and work with Web API.